# Sum datetime differences based on column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
        field1    field2    field3
time
  t1         1         1         1
  t2         1         1         0
  t3         2         3         1
  t4         3         3         0
  t5         1         2         0
```

Times are in the form `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`, and are currently indexing the dataframe.

`field 1` and  `field 2` are used to identify items, such that the tuple `(field1,field2)` corresponds to a specific sensor somewhere in the world. `field 3` is the value of that sensor at the given time, and takes either the value 0 or 1.

I'd like the group the dataframe by (field1, field2) and sum the total time that each sensor takes each value from field 3. So, if `t1='2016-07-20 00:00:00'` and `t2='2016-07-20 00:01:00'`, and the current time is `'2016-07-20 00:03:00'`, I would have a new dataframe that looks like:

```
            field3=0    field3=1
(1,1)          2 min       1 min
(2,3)            ...         ...
(3,3)            ...         ...  
(1,2)            ...         ...
```

I assume that from `t1` to `t2`, `field3`'s value is 1, and from `t2` onwards it is 0 because (1,1) doesn't appear again in the dataframe. The `1 min` is from `t2 - t1` and the `2 min` is from `current_time - t2`

The `2 min` and `1 min` can be any format (be it total minutes/seconds, a timedelta, or whatever)

I've tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict, namedtuple

# so i can create a defaultdict(Field3) and save some logic
class Field3(object):
    def __init__(self):
            self.zero= pd.Timedelta('0 days')
            self.one = pd.Timedelta('0 days')

# used to map to field3 in a dictionary
Sensor = namedtuple('Sensor','field1 field2')

# the dataframe mentioned above
df = pd.DataFrame(...)

# iterate through each  row of the dataframe and map from (field1,field2) to
# field3, adding time based on the value of field3 in the frame and the 
# time difference between this row and the next
rows = list(df.iterrows())
sensor_to_field3 = defaultdict(Field3)
for i in xrange(len(rows)-1):
        sensor = Sensor(field1=rows[i][1][0],field2=rows[i][1][1])
        if rows[i][1][2]: sensor_to_field3[spot].one += rows[i+1][0]-rows[i][0]
        else: spot_to_status[spot].zero += rows[i+1][0]-rows[i][0]
spot_to_status = {k:[v] for k,v in sensor_to_field3.iteritems()}
result = pd.DataFrame(sensor_to_field3,index=[0])
```

It gets me basically but I want (though it currently only works when there's a single sensor represented in the entire table, which I don't really want to have to deal with if there's a better way of solving this).

I feel like there has to be a better way of going about this. Something like do a groupby on `field1,field2`, then aggregate timedeltas based on `field3` and the `time` index, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it, in case anyone else runs into something remotely similar. Still not sure if it's optimal, but it feels better than what I was doing.

I changed the original dataframe to include the time as a column, and just use integer indices.

```
def create_time_deltas(dataframe):
    # add a timedelta column
    dataframe['timedelta'] = pd.Timedelta(minutes=0)
    # iterate over each row and set the timedelta to the difference of the next one and this one
    for i in dataframe.index[:-1]:
            dataframe.set_value(i,'timedelta',dataframe.loc[i+1,'time']dataframe.loc[i,'time'])
    # set the last time value, which couldn't be set earlier because index out of bounds
    dataframe.set_value(i+1,'timedelta',pd.to_datetime(datetime.now())-dataframe.loc[i,'time'])
    return dataframe

def group_by_field3_time(dataframe, start=None, stop=None):
    # optionally set time bounds on what to care about
    stop = stop or pd.to_datetime(datetime.now())
    recent = dataframe.loc[logical_and(start < df['time'] , df['time'] < stop)]
    # groupby and apply to create a new dataframe with the time_deltas column 
    by_td = df.groupby(['field1','field2']).apply(create_time_deltas)
    # sum the timedeltas for each triple, which can be used later
    by_oc = by_td.groupby(['field1','field2','field3']).sum()
    return by_oc
```

If anyone can think of a better way to do this I'm all ears, but this does feel a lot better than creating dictionaries all over the place.